# Merging base URL and index page for social media counters (Facebook, Twitter, Plus1)

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, google-plus-one, tweets, base-url

Looking for help in connecting the way social media counters count the likes on a base URL and the base URL with file name.

I have three counters (Facebook likes, Plus1 likes, and Tweets) on different story pages on my site.  All of these page names are currently index.shtml.  Within my coding, I am consistent at referring to these pages as "/programs/mystory/" rather than "/programs/mystory/index.shtml."  However, some people manage to make it to the index.shtml addresses anyway. Using the Open Graph meta tags, I can indicate the url to be liked.  However, how do I make the count interchangeable between base URL likes and base+index?

Live example:

These two URLs go to the same page:
http://being.publicradio.org/programs/2011/mormon-demystified/

http://being.publicradio.org/programs/2011/mormon-demystified/index.shtml

However, if you view that page from the first URL, you see 543 Facebook Likes, **8 Plus 1 Likes**, and 32 Tweets.  If you view it from the second URL (complete with file name) you see 0 Facebook Likes, 1 Plus 1 Like, and 0 Tweets.  Regardless of the URL, when you look at this page, I want you to see 543 Facebook Likes, **9 Plus 1 Likes**, and 32 Tweets.

Can anyone assist?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Always use the longer version of the URL.  Be sure to place it in the OG tags, canonical link reference as well as hard-coding the data-href form the plugins.